# Installing Axel?

Tags: installation, apt, 11.04

How do I install `axel` on Natty Narwhal? I tried `sudo apt-get install axel` but it came back with this:

```
james@james-ubuntu-11-04:~$ sudo apt-get install axel
[sudo] password for james: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package axel
james@james-ubuntu-11-04:~$
```

does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Deleting because its actually just stupidity/whatever you want to call it, since I was running 11.04 (the pre-release) at the time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Axel is available in Natty (I just checked it). Ensure you've done a `sudo apt-get update` and see if it shows up.

Comment: Did the trick! I had to do that for Thunderbird as well... Hmm. Fresh Natty install (A mere five hours old now), so I'm going to file a bug on launchpad.

Comment: I'm not sure it's a bug; you should always do an update first when running the dev release as it's always changing.